# Flowchart to script converter

Tags: python, perl, drakon, drakon-editor

Is there any open source tool capable to generate python or perl scripts from a flowchart? AFAIK, Labview is the only tool really able to do this. I need this in order to simplify scripting for low-technical-skilled users.

Any other suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

EDITED:
For anyone interested in this subject, I've found [Drakon Editor](http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/), a nice [graphical code composer for Python](http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/python/python.html#own_code), C/C++ and Tcl:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about following tools for Perl:

- [Perl Node Interface](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pni/)
- [VECT](http://www.complex.iastate.edu/download/Vect/index.html) - although this is quite specialized

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Perl module **Devel::Graph** will help you, please check it.
I hope that what are you looking for.

[CPAN module Devel::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Devel-Graph-0.12/lib/Devel/Graph.pm)

Comment: Thanks for your response but this seems to be the opposite to what I want. I actually need flowchart to code conversion.

Answer (score 0):

http://flowgorithm.org/index.html can create code from flowcharts. You can also run the flowcharts.